# Netflix Zuul filters pulled from Cassandra not working

Tags: java, groovy, cassandra, servlet-filters, netflix-zuul

I have been using Zuul in combination with other Netflix OSS softs like Eureka, Hystrix, etc. At first, I was able to create my own filter and make it work from the FileSystem. Then, I wanted to use ZuulFilterDAOCassandra API to be able to pull filters from a Cassandra database. The problem is that I'm not able to make it work.

I have translated the Java filter I used from the FileSystem to a Groovy filter, and added it to Cassandra using the `ZuulFilterDAO.addFilter()` method, and activate it using `ZuulFilterDAO.setFilterActive()`.After that, I started the `ZuulFilterPoller` to start pulling the filters from the database, if it already had any. For the database table model, I assumed it by looking at the `FilterInfo` object and its attributes, and from the `ZuulFilterDAOCassandra.addFilter()`method.

Here's a more complete section of code :

```
ZuulFilterDAO dao = new ZuulFilterDAOCassandra(keyspace);
try {
    FilterInfo fi = dao.addFilter(code, "pre", "testFilter", "false", "1");
    dao.setFilterActive(fi.getFilterName(), 1); // 1 is the filter revision
    ZuulFilterPoller.start(dao);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Logging
}

// Show every active filter
List<FilterInfo> allActiveFilters = dao.getAllActiveFilters();
for (FilterInfo fi : allActiveFilters) {
    LOG.info("FilterName: " + fi.getFilterName()); // outputs : FilterName: testFilter
}
```

In the Zuul console, I also get the following :

```
adding filter to diskFilterInfo{filter_id='zuul-server:testFilter:pre', 
filter_name='testFilter', filter_type='pre', revision=1, creationDate=/*date*/,
isActive=true, isCanary=false, application_name=zuul-server}

filter written testFilter.groovy
```

I can then edit the testFilter.groovy at the root of my project, which contains the code I have mentioned in the `dao.addFilter()` method. I know the code is working, since it worked when pulling filters from the FS. And, when adding a filter, there's a verification of the code done by `FilterVerifier`.

And when I send my http requests to my application, Zuul doesn't filter them anymore. Am I missing something ?

Comment: 1. Have you tried running the code without the try-catch? As shown, exceptions are being ignored. 2. Are you using the FilterFileManager to detect the Groovy filters?

Comment: OK I forgot to use the FilterFileManager here. I used it to pull filters from the FS, but not to pull from cass. Thank you, write it as an answer and I'll accept it. For the record, exceptions are being caught, as I once tried to activate a filter twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [FilterFileManager](http://netflix.github.io/zuul/javadoc/zuul-core/com/netflix/zuul/FilterFileManager.html). It's my understanding that ZuulFilterPoller saves the filters from Cassandra to disk, and the FilterFileManager puts them to work.

Comment: Indeed, filters are polled and saved to disk, and the FFM handles the compiling/processing of the filters. Still don't know how I forgot about it...